# Рациональная организация многопточности java

Tags: java, многопоточность

У меня три *SQL* запроса возвращают данные, которые я обрабатываю и собираю итоговую структуру для каждого запроса.

```
listSql1<String[]>, listSql2<String[]>, listSql3<String[]>.
```

далее эти структуры нужно обрабатывать, -каждый по собственной логике.

```
listSql1 = voidList1(listSql1);
listSql2 = voidList2(listSql2);
```

`listSql3` нуждается в данных из `listSql1` и `listSql2`, которые получаются уже после обработки методами `voidList1` и `voidList2` соответственно.

```
listSql3 = voidList3(listSql3, listSql2, listSql1);
```

методы `voidListХХХ` они очень затратны, т.к. структуры которые они обрабатывают, могут содержать до 2-3 миллионов строк с массивами длинной в 5-15 ячеек.

Вопрос:

Мне лучше параллельно организовать многопоточность с выполнением `voidList1` и `voidList2`, а потом уже подключать многопоточность для `voidList3`?

Или есть идеи, как более эффективно организовать многопоточность для моего случая?

Comment: если я правильно понял, нужно согласовать что бы 3 таска выполнялась после того как 1 и 2 завершились в потоках? Для этого можно использовать CountDownLatch (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) или CompletableFuture(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html). Не совсем понятно, какой объем данных возвращают обработчики voidList1, voidList2, у Вас точно хватит оперативной памяти? Есть ли возможность выполнять voidList3 на основе части данных из voidList1 и voidList2?

Comment: CompletableFuture да посмотрел доку это то что нужно. возвращают voidList1 и voidList2 около 2 млн строк в сумме, оператива 8Гб проверю опытным путем.=) нет на основе части данных никак не получиться, т.к. заполнение их непредсказуемо исходя из загружаемых данных.

Comment: а зачем такое количество данных с базы тянуть? прямо на базе посчитать нельзя? например с помощью хранимой процедуры и вернуть курсор с результатами

Comment: да так и сделано, вытягиваются только самые необходимые и уже по максимум отфильтрованные данные, просто много очень.

Comment: 2млн - это не много, но я сильно не уверен, что их именно нужно тянуть с базы. С другой стороны, всегда есть возможность делать расчет с запоминанием - тогда не нужно будет постоянно это все считать. В любом случае, самое первое, что я бы сделал - это профилирование и понял бы, где тупит. Может оно 90% времени тянет с базы - в этом случае никакое распаралеливание не поможет.